# How do I get total text and voice channel count in numbers

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried using `text = str(ctx.guild.text_channels)` and `voice = str(ctx.guild.voice_channels)` for my embed, but it returns a full list of every channel with all kinds of unnecessary info. How do I simplify it to just "`15` channels" and "`7` VCs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are returning the amount as a string, in which would produce the name, instead by using `len`, it would find the length of all the channels and return it with the channel count.

```
total_text_channels = len(ctx.guild.text_channels)
total_voice_channels = len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
total_channels = total_text_channels + total_voice_channels
```

Then simply using the `total_text_channels` and `total_voice_channels` as a `str` variable:

```
str(total_text_channels)
str(total_voice_channels)
str(total_channels)
```

If you wanted, you can also get the total channel amount

Answer (score 1):

Use `len()` to get the length of a list.

```
num_voice_channels = len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
num_text_channels = len(ctx.guild.text_channels)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ctx.guild.text_channels` returns you a *list* of `discord.TextChannel` in the guild. You can get the length of a list by using `len(list)`.

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title='Channels', description=f'There are {len(ctx.guild.text_channels)} text channels and {len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)} voice channels in guild.')
```